# MySQL query hanging with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm only a dabbler in databases - using them for backends for basic web applications, never anything enterprise.

I've recently needed to work with two tables - one with 130,000 rows and the other with 29,000 rows. They have similar data and I need to pull from them with some sort of JOIN statement. Unfortunately this seems to cause issues and the query sits and hangs.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM call_status LEFT JOIN queue_log 
ON call_status.callId = queue_log.callid 
ORDER BY call_status.callId DESC limit 10;
```

When checking the *processlist*, I see the following:

```
Query   643 Copying to tmp table    SELECT * FROM call_status LEFT JOIN queue_log ON call_status.callId = queue_log.callid ORDER BY call
```

Yes, the query has been running for over 10 minutes.

I've run an *explain* and this it the output:

```
1   SIMPLE  call_status ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  28954   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  queue_log   ALL ix_queue_log_callid (null)  (null)  (null)  130419
```

I've run a *SHOW INDEX* on both tables, both look fine to me:

**call_status:**

```
call_status 0   PRIMARY 1   callId  A   28954   (null)  (null)      BTREE   
call_status 0   ix_order_callId 1   callId  A   28954   (null)  (null)      BTREE
```

**queue_log:**

```
queue_log   1   ix_queue_log_callid 1   callid  A   26083   (null)  (null)      BTREE
```

I'm at a complete loss, and it's 2am here.

Comment: Try adding a `DESC` index on `call_status.callId`.

Comment: @Lieven: MySQL has only one kind of indexes (`ASC`).

Comment: @ypercube - I had no idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM call_status 
        ORDER BY callId DESC 
        LIMIT 10
     ) AS st
  LEFT JOIN 
      queue_log AS qlog 
    ON 
      st.callId = qlog.callid 
ORDER BY 
      st.callId DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi ypercube.

Thanks, that query ran really quickly! I'll still have to fiddle around to make the results exactly what I want, but the speed is fantastic.

Could you please explain to me a bit why that is faster and how that nested query works?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like selecting last 10 call_status

```
SELECT * FROM call_status ORDER BY callId DESC limit 10;
```

after that, in server side code (php, asp, jsp, ruby) get a list of all this id's that will look like (3,4,5,6,7,90)

and do

```
SELECT * FROM queue_log WHERE callid IN (3,4,5,6,7,90)
```

and join these two lists in you server side code

or you can create virtual tables to do the same thing but on database side